# How to resolve error TS2731 in the following code snippet?

Tags: typescript, generics, constraints

I am actually studying from a book and have the following code, however the following code results in an error.

```
// Define a function named printProperty that takes two generic type parameters
function printProperty<T, K extends keyof T>
 (object: T, key: K) {
 let propertyValue = object[key];
 console.log(`object[${key}] = ${propertyValue}`);
}

let obj1 = {
 id: 1,
 name: "myName",
 print() { console.log(`${this.id}`) }
}

printProperty(obj1, "id");
printProperty(obj1, "name");
```

The error:

```
index.ts(5,25): error TS2731: Implicit conversion of a 'symbol' to a 'string' will fail at runtime. Consider wrapping this expression in 'String(...)'.
```

I tried disabling the strict option in the config file too but that didn't work.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keys in the object have the following type:

```
type PropertyKey = string | number | symbol;
```

Therefore, `keyof T` includes `symbol` and wrapping `symbol` with string is considered invalid.

You can refactor `K` to either extend only `string` keys of `T` or numbers as well if you need them:

Only `string` keys:

```
K extends keyof T & string
```

`string` and `number` keys:

```
K extends keyof T & (string | number)
```